# Could some one help me with powershell to export User properties with computer name

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm looking for a PowerShell script to export User properties with the help of ComputerName
**(i.e, Input excel = Computer name, output = User details like Identity, Contact Information)**

Just wanted to share that Since computer and user properties are different we can use the below method

**Part 1** - Fetch the **UPN** from **ComputerName - Source file excelsheet**

**Edit** -- At last, I found the solution to get a Registered user for. Computer with below commands but I'm stuck with the separate sheets now device name in 1 and owner in another sheet.
could someone help to rearrange 1 sheet to have both computer name, device owners, and other info that I'm pulling from below step 2?

```
 $csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\Computers.csv
$ObjectID = foreach ($item in $csv){
    Write-Host $item.DisplayName
# just output the result, it will be collected in variable $ObjectID
    Get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($item.DisplayName)'" | Select-Object ObjectID
}

$ObjectID | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Desktop\BulkObjectID.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation

$csv2 = Import-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\BulkObjectID.csv
$Owners = foreach ($item in $csv2){
# just output the result, it will be collected in variable $Owners
    Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId $item.ObjectID | Select-Object mail
}

$Owners | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Desktop\Owners.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

**Part 2** - Use the **UPN** and fetch the **user information (email Id, Location etc)**

**This Powershell will complete part 2**

```
Import-csv '/Users/UPN_withcomputername.csv' | ForEach-Object {Get-AzADUser -Filter "mail eq '$_'"| Select-Object userPrincipalName,mail,Id,City etc...} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | export-csv '/completereport.csv'
```

***basically I'm looking for collating all the info into one sheet now like below now***

- Computer name, registered users, user location
- Test1, Sathish, India

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code vending machine. Start trying to solve the problem on your own, then come back and ask _specific programming-related questions_ when you reach a particular part you're unable to solve on your own.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question (and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), if relevant).

Comment: As mentioned I'm able to fetch the user information from UPN or email ID from the PowerShell that I have I just need help for the first part to fetch the UPN or email ID of a computer from azure.

Comment: As an aside: if you want your CSV file to be read into _objects_ whose properties you can reference, use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), not `Get-Content`.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I figured out how to get the user information for a particular computer. Thanks for all your wonderful support :-)

```
Connect-AzureAD

Start-Transcript -Path "Filepath\Export_User.txt" -Append

###### From Hostname Object ID will be Fetched -- to be used to get the User Information in Next Script ######
==================================================================================================
$ComputerName = Import-Csv Filepath\Computers.csv
$ObjectID = foreach ($item in $ComputerName){
    Write-Host $item.DisplayName
    Get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($item.DisplayName)'" | Select-Object ObjectID, DisplayName
}
$ObjectID | Export-Csv -Path Filepath\ObjectID.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation


###### This script will save the User information of particular Computer ######
==================================================================================================
$ComputerObjectId = Import-Csv Filepath\ObjectID.csv
$AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner = foreach ($item in $ComputerObjectId){

    Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId $item.ObjectID | Select-Object @{n='ComputerName';e={$item.DisplayName}},@{n='Computer_ObjectID';e={$item.ObjectID}},Mail,UserPrincipalName,DisplayName,GivenName,MailNickName,JobTitle,Department,State,StreetAddress,Surname,TelephoneNumber,Mobile,PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName,PostalCode,UsageLocation,City,CompanyName,Country,UserState,UserStateChangedOn,UserType,ObjectId,ObjectType,AccountEnabled,ImmutableId,LastDirSyncTime,PreferredLanguage,ShowInAddressList
}
$AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner | Export-Csv -Path Filepath\User_Information.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation


###### Delete ObjectID.csv File ######
========================================================
$FileName = "Filepath\ObjectID.csv"

$Testpath = Test-Path $FileName
if ($Testpath -eq $true)
{
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Deleting Old file **ObjectID.csv file**"
  Remove-Item $FileName -Force
}
else
{
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "File **ObjectID.csv** is already deleted or Does not exist"
}

Stop-Transcript
```